# Multidimensinal array handing in PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to create unique playlist. regarding that my DB structure is...

```
aid (albumid)    |    sid (songid)    |    rid (artistid)
_________________|____________________|___________________

5001             |    track-a         |    a    
5002             |    track-a         |    c    
5001             |    track-a         |    a:b
5001             |    track-a         |    b
5001             |    track-a         |    b:c
5001             |    track-b         |    b
5001             |    track-b         |    b:a
```

Its like this 5001 number album may have any number of song with name sid as track-1, but each time it is differentiated with unique artists like it is sung by artist a, b, c, if it sung by duet than I have differentiate it with `:` that is these artist combination have also sung this. Now at time of insertion I wish to check combination if it already exist. My PHP code is

```
$track is array of track
$artist is array of artist (for artist combination array value may have ":", I have taken it as string.)
//SELECT QUERY FOR ALBUM
if (mysql_num_rows($sql) != 0) {
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
            $album_array[] = array( $row["sid"], $row["rid"]);
        }
    for ($z = 0; $z < count($track); $z++) {
    if( in_array($track["z"],$album_array[0]) && empty(array_diff(explode(":",$album_array[1]), explode(":",$artist["z"]) )) ){
       echo 'true';
    } else {
       echo 'false';    
    }
}

} else {
 //SIMPLE INSERT CODE HERE
}
```

For combination

```
  track-a    |    a
  track-a    |    b
  track-a    |    b:a
  track-a    |    a:c
```

It should return me

```
-TRUE
-TRUE
-TRUE
-FALSE
```

but its returning me false each time. Please help me out.

Comment: What is in the `$track` array?

Comment: Group of values that each I want to compare against `$album_array`

Comment: An example of the values like you showed the album values might help.

Answer (score 0):

```
$track["z"] and $artist["z"]
```

should be

```
$track[$z] and $artist[$z]
```

You are only checking against the first array `$album_array[0]`. Is there only one returned?

Code page example: http://codepad.org/lE8eUBHY

Comment: @Tisha try to echo out each condition to help you debug it.

Comment: I am creating multidimension array here. that is `$album_array[$key][0|1]` respective rid and sid would be assigned and these are string while fetching it as table.

Comment: what's use of following code when I am assigning keys of $album_array[$key][] arrays. Please elaborate completely confused.

Comment: I got the problem.. issue in `in_array` condition. that is I wish to check $album_array[][0] position. How can I do with this. that is use $album_array[$key][0] in `in_array`? as using same giving me fatal error.

Comment: @Tisha So, for each `track` you need to look for it in each album array?

Comment: Yes exactly each `track`(for these i have used loop) I wanna see in `$album_array[][0]` at position 0 only this way...